# Excel Index formula that accounts for 2 row variables

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a lot of raw data from a system and would like to make it easier to read.

It is a lot more data than I show here but the principle is the same. One case number is repeated in multiple rows in the raw data as shown by “raw data” picture.

I would like to transform that data so it looks like the “solution” picture.
I tried using a pivot table but I can’t get the text to show there I only get numbers and If I use an index formula I can’t account for more than the case number to acquire the correct row. And in my sample data I need to account for the case number first and then the group name in order to find the correct row.

Is excel the right program or should I look somewhere else? Thankful for the help!

[Raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LL8wJ.png)

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3eoU.png)

Comment: Try with Pivot until you succeed.

Comment: @Vityata According to my searches that isn't possible?:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b1b6de6b-6b29-4113-a299-3cb3243d9a48/text-in-the-value-field-of-an-excel-pivot-table?forum=excel

Comment: sry, Patrick, looked like a typical trivial Pivot. However, if you want, you may replace all the unique string values with numbers, make a pivot, copy it and replace back... With VBA it is doable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your raw data is in `Sheet1` and solution needs to be displayed in `Sheet2` following might be helpful.

To display `Category 1 (Group 1, Group 2, Group 3, ....)` in a row, enter the following formula in `Cell B1` of `Sheet2`:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$31, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($A$1:A$1, Sheet1!$B$2:$B$31), 0))
```

This is an array formula so commit this formula by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Drag/copy this formula across as required.

To display `Category 2 (Answer 1, Answer 2, Answer 3, ....)` in rows under `Category 1` enter the following formula in `Cell B2` of `Sheet2`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$31, MATCH(0, COUNTIF(B$1:B1,Sheet2!$C$2:$C$31)+IF(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$31<>B$1, 1, 0), 0)), 0)
```

Again this is an array formula so commit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Drag/copy this formula across and down as required.

See image for reference.

[image]

***Note:*** Change range in formula as required.

Comment: Thank you! it helped a lot!
Unfortunately my wote doesnt count since i have less than 15 points :/